# is there a way to write a script to automatically save the metaoutput file into our desired file path

Tags: logging

I want to write a script to save .tml files to my desired file path

currently I am saving it manually by clicking on file name and exporting it to the file path.
I think it is better to save the file automatically into the desired file path

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible in actual version of MetaOutput (2.1.*).
It will be possible in MetaOutput 3.0.

This command will write your output into file:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("@@@EXPORT _your_file_.tml");
```

If you need to export only some specific sources command will be next:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("@@@EXPORT _your_file_.tml &&&SOURCE _SOURCE1_ _SOURCE2_");
```